# Filtering a Dataset by another Dataset in R using two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

The task I am trying to accomplish is essentially filtering one dataframe by the entries in another dataframe by entries in two columns.
I have the dataframe sdata, which have UserId and ClusterNum(and others columns too), and the dataframe users, with that two columns too.
I need to filter user, by matching these pairs of Columns.
I tried

```
users[users[,c("userId","ClusterNum")] %in% sdata[,c("userId","ClusterNum")],]
```

but that returned a empty dataframe.

sdata is generate from Users:

```
cdata <- ddply(users, c("userId","ClusterNum"), summarise,
           N    = length(ClusterNum),
           mean = mean(rating),
           total = N*mean)
sdata <- ddply(cdata, .(userId), function(x) x[which.max(x$total),])
```

And users is a rating dataset from http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip

with movies dataset scaled, pca generated, clusterized by a k-means algorithm.

Columns from dataset Users:

```
colnames(users)
   [1] "userId"     "movieId"    "rating"     "timestamp"  "ClusterNum"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: You need to get the rows of users, which have the same userId as sdata?

Comment: rows of user which have the same userId and same clusterNum as sdata

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i've found a pretty simple solution:

```
matches <-users[c(which( outer(users$ClusterNum, sdata$ClusterNum, "==") & 
outer(users$userId, sdata$userId, "=="), arr.ind=TRUE) ),]
```